# Bug ruby csv parsing

Tags: ruby, csv

Hello something is wrong with my code
I'm trying to open two CSV files in the same `.rb` file in ruby and I got this error:

```
undefined method `modele_fill' for 17936:Integer (NoMethodError)
```

with this code

```rb
su = Super_hash.new.modele_fill(MODELE_DOCUMENT)
su.cat_fill(CATEGORIE_DOCUMENT)
su.solve(PROBLEME_DOCUMENT)
```

when i do this

```rb
su = Super_hash.new.cat_fill(MODELE_DOCUMENT)
su.modele_fill(CATEGORIE_DOCUMENT)
su.solve(PROBLEME_DOCUMENT)
```

the functions are working alone but when you try to use another one on the same file you got an error how is it possible ?

the ARGUMENT is the name of the csv file and this is my code

```rb
require "csv"
CATEGORIE_DOCUMENT = "Catégories.csv"
MODELE_DOCUMENT = "Modèles.csv"
PROBLEME_DOCUMENT = "moto et loisir SEPT 2021.csv"

class Super_hash
  def initialize
    @hash_modele = {}
    @hash_item   = {}
  end

  def modele_fill(document_csv)
    files = CSV.parse(File.read(document_csv), headers: true) do |file|
      salope = file[0].split(";")

      salope[4] = "Unknown" if salope[4] == ""
      salope.delete("")

      #next if salope.count == 1
      
      if salope.count == 6
        salope.append(salope[2]) 
        modele = salope[6].to_sym

        @hash_modele[modele] = {}
        @hash_modele[modele][:id] = salope[0]
        @hash_modele[modele][:id_marque] = salope[1]
        @hash_modele[modele][:marque]    = salope[2]
        @hash_modele[modele][:categorie] = salope[3]
        @hash_modele[modele][:sous_categories] = salope[4]
        @hash_modele[modele][:cylindre] = salope[5]
        @hash_modele[modele][:word] = {}
        @hash_modele[modele][:word][0] = modele.to_s.downcase.split
      else
        var = salope[6..].sort{|x,y| y.length <=> x.length}
        modele = var[0].to_sym

        @hash_modele[modele] = {}
        @hash_modele[modele][:id] = salope[0]
        @hash_modele[modele][:id_marque] = salope[1]
        @hash_modele[modele][:marque]    = salope[2]
        @hash_modele[modele][:categorie] = salope[3]
        @hash_modele[modele][:sous_categories] = salope[4]
        @hash_modele[modele][:cylindre] = salope[5]
        @hash_modele[modele][:word] = {}

        for i in 0..var[0..].count-1
          @hash_modele[modele][:word][i] = var[i]
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def cat_fill(csv_item_file)
    file = CSV.parse(File.read(csv_item_file), headers: true) do |file|
      ligne = file[0].split(";")
      ligne.delete("")
      print ligne

      next if ligne[2] == "0" 

      if ligne.count == 5 
        item = ligne[4].to_sym

        @hash_item[item] ={}
        @hash_item[item][:cat]  = ligne[0]
        @hash_item[item][:scat] = ligne[1]
        @hash_item[item][:sscat]= ligne[2]
        @hash_item[item][:tic]  = ligne[3]
        @hash_item[item][:word] = {}
        @hash_item[item][:word][0] = item.to_s.downcase
      else
        var = ligne[4..].sort{|x,y| y.length <=> x.length}
        item  = var[0].to_sym

        @hash_item[item] = {}
        @hash_item[item][:cat]  = ligne[0]
        @hash_item[item][:scat] = ligne[1]
        @hash_item[item][:sscat]= ligne[2]
        @hash_item[item][:tic]  = ligne[3]
        @hash_item[item][:word] = {}
        for i in 0..var.count-1
          @hash_item[item][:word][i]  = var[i].downcase.to_s
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def solve(pb_csv)
    file = CSV.parse(File.read(pb_csv), headers: true) do |file|
      line = file[0].split(";")

      line[40].include?("  -  ") ? modele = line[40].partition("-  ").last : modele = line[40].partition(" - ").last
      print modele
    end
  end
end

su = Super_hash.new.modele_fill(MODELE_DOCUMENT)
su.cat_fill(CATEGORIE_DOCUMENT)
su.solve(PROBLEME_DOCUMENT)
```

Comment: I cannot understand how either option works since neither `modele_fill` nor `cat_fill` return the instance of `Super_hash` (hint). Second are you sure the error doesn't occur in your second example rather than your first?

Comment: i just tested them right now and both works so ....

Comment: quite literally impossible https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/ShadyEntireInternalcommand#main.rb